# How To Get Timezone Of Date In Swift

Tags: swift, date, timezone

I only want to get the current date object's timezone. The Date class in Swift does not have a way to do so. I have seen ways to convert from one timezone to another. But no way to do so extracting the timezone from a date object.

Why is that?

Is there a way to do so? Thoughts on how? Thanks

Comment: Dates don’t have time zones. They’re simply a point in time. E.g., the moment in which Neil Armstrong stepped foot on the moon. You could describe that moment in UTC, or EST, or any other TZ (or even in other calendar systems), but they’re all referring to the same moment, and would be modelled by a singular date object. Internally, they’re just a Double that counts the number of secs since the reference date. Any time zones you see relating to dates are just an interpretive layer on top of that (e.g. print will call `.description`, which will format it to your local tz for your convenience.).

Comment: ok thank you for the input. i know how to do the rest now. I still wonder as well why DateFormatter only has a param that accepts a string date, not a date object

Comment: @chitgoks DateFormatter accepts a `String` that describes the format and then a `Date` for the actual date to express in that format. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter

Comment: yes that is correct. i found it somewhat weird that dateofrmatter only accepts a string date. but not a date object.

Comment: Alexander, your answer-as-comment is excellent. I particularly like your "the moment Neil Armstrong stepped foot on the moon" example. You should post your comment as an answer as it really does answer the question. (And I am eager to up-vote it. Do you mind if I borrow your example?)

Comment: DateFormatters will convert Date objects to Strings or String objects to dates. Both of those conversions **do** require a time zone. Take a look at the function [DateFormatter.string(From:Date)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1415810-string)

Comment: Hi @DuncanC yes. that's right. What i meant was there is no param for DateFormatter to accept a date and then output as a new date object once the timezone is set on the formatter. One has to convert it to string then back to date for that.

Answer (score 0):

Dates don’t have time zones. They’re simply a point in time.

E.g., the moment in which Neil Armstrong stepped foot on the moon. You could describe that moment in UTC, or EST, or any other TZ (or even in other calendar systems), but they’re all referring to the same *moment*. That would be modelled by a singular date object.

By another analogy, an object has a width, but it doesn't know its unit. Its width can be measured in centimetres, inches, plank lengths or light years. These are all abstractions we put on top of the concept of distance, and they all describe the same thing.

Internally, they’re just a Double that counts the number of secs since the reference date. Clearly, there's no timezone there.

Any time zones you see relating to dates are just an interpretive layer on top of that (e.g. print will call `.description`, which will format it to your local tz for your convenience.).